# Java hashcode for String Array

Tags: java

I want to create a hashcode and equal functions for an object that contain a two dimensional array of string like String[][]. How to create an efficient hashcode and equal functions in which the contents of rows are matched. For example, I want the following to be matched.

```
String[][] str1={{"A","B"},{"C","D","E"}};
String[][] str2={{"C","D","E"},{"A","B"}};
```

The code generated by eclipse or netbean doesn't work. I guess there could be a problem (possible hash collisions) to iterate through all cells of the array and then sum the hashcode of individual cell like below. Even the commented line does not work.

```
int hash =0, xor=tran[0][0].hashCode()*97;
    for(int i=0;i<tran.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<tran[i].length;j++){
            hash+=tran[i][j].hashCode()*97;
            //hash= hash*97 + tran[i][j].hashCode();
            xor^=tran[i][j].hashCode()*97;
        }
    }
```

Will there be any problem in using XOR like the third statement within nested loops.

Comment: If the first array is supposed to be equal to the second one, you could probably define them as `Set<List<String>>` instead of a 2-dimensional arrays. Your equals and hashCode methods would be extremely simple then: you could just use `str1.equals(str2)` and `str1.hashCode()`.

Comment: What you mean by equal? do you mean the length? The lengths are not equal

Comment: I mean equal as in `a.equals(b)`. Didn't you say yourself that you wanted str1 to be considered equal to str2 by your equals() method? If I understand it right, you could probably define your values as Set<List<String>> instead of String[][].

Comment: Yes str1.equal(str2) should be true. But I cannot use Set<Object> because I need the index of the rows. And in set i cannot retrieve object in the same order in which they are inserted.

Comment: What about LinkedHashSet<List<String>>?

Comment: The two arrays arent equal then - because calling array[0] on each one gives you a different result. Its reasonable to assume that if array1 equals array2 then array1[0] == array2[0].

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you want to ignore the order of the inner arrays in the outer array. The `Set` contract is what you need: `Set` equals and hashCode methods assume no specific order of elements. The `Set` elements can be `List` (if `{"C", "D", "E"}` is not equal to `{"D", "C", "E"}`) or again `Set` (if inner elements order also doesn't matter). So it's better to get rid of arrays and store your data in `Set<List<String>>` or `Set<Set<String>>`. Here's an example how you can convert it:

```
public static Set<List<String>> asSet(String[][] input) {
    Set<List<String>> result = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    for(String[] row : input) {
        result.add(Arrays.asList(row));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
String[][] str1={{"A","B"},{"C","D","E"}};
String[][] str2={{"C","D","E"},{"A","B"}};

Set<List<String>> set1 = asSet(str1);
Set<List<String>> set2 = asSet(str2);
System.out.println(set1.equals(set2)); // true
```

So you don't need any special objects, just use what's already provided in JDK.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used LinkedHashSet<List<String>> as i need that the object should maintain insertion order.

Comment: @user5307652 he also used same type. But he also mentioned how would you fit your 2D array into this set.

Answer (score 0):

if you need str1[][] to have a the same hashcode as str2[][], you can use the integral value of each char at the array, for example:

String[][] str1={{"A","B"},{"C","D","E"}};

str1Hashcode = int(A)*0 + int(B)*1 + int(C)*0 + int(D)*1 + int(E)*2

applying the same ot str2Hashcode, where 0, 1, ... are the column number, by doing so the hashcode for a given two dimensional array will be matched to any array contains the same rows regardless their order.

Comment: int ascii = (int) character;   the ascii value of 'A' = 65, use the integral value as of each char in the 2D array with its column number as a key and sum all these keys to get your hashcode, So your 2D arrays will have the same hashcode regardless of its rows order, does this make sense for you!

Comment: First of all the data type is String not Char. Second it wont work for char either. because you are multiplying first with zero, that mean it will ignore what ever is at that position.

Comment: Okay start with index = 1 for the first position, then 2...and so on
why it won't work for chars!! and in case of strings you the hashcode of each string multiplied with its position starting with index = 1 !!!

Answer (score -2):

```
String[][] str1={{"A","B"},{"C","D","E"}};    
str1[0][0].hashCode=65 (Ascii code of 'A')
str1[0][1].hashCode=66 (Ascii code of 'B')
```

In your code it doesnot take `C`,`D`,`E`. because these are ignored by compiler..

package com.bnymellon.javaprograms;
public class Test11 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[][] str1={{"A","B"},{"C","D","E"}};
    String[][] str2={{"C","D","E"},{"A","B"}};
    String[][] str3={{"G","c"},{"f","B","c"}};
    int n=2;
    for(int i=0;i<1;i++)
         for(int j=0;j<20;j++)
        {   
            System.out.println(str1[i][j]);   
        }
}
```

}
output:
A
B
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at com.bnymellon.javaprograms.Test11.main(Test11.java:14)